# Xcode: Navigation Bar not selectable after table view cell page navigation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I have a UIViewController, which has a Navigation Controller embedded in it, and it also has a table view with several populated cells. If I tap on a cell it brings me to another page, and then when I go back to the table view page, the navigation bar no longer works. I'm unsure as to what is causing this to happen.

This is how I navigate to the new page after a table view cell has selected.

```
let itemPage = ItemPageViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(itemPage, animated: true)
```

[image: Page 1 with table view and working nav bar]
[image: Page 2 representing selected cell, nav bar is working]
[image: Page 3 with table view and not working nav bar]